# Stored Proc returning one row, recordset or output parameters?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Ignoring ORM / NHibernate, etc. Consider the common requirement to pass in a Unique ID and return data from a single row (if the ID is found).  The two ways to do this would be to return a record set or to use output parameters.  Stored proc would be called from .NET C# code - so from that point of view one requires the set up / reading of additional parameters with an ExecuteNonQuery, whilst the other requires an ExecuteScalar and the accessing / reading of a DataReader.

Are there any real benefits over using one vs the other?

```
CREATE PROC GetUserByRecordSet
  @UserID UniqueIdentifier
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      ID,
      Name,
      EmailAddress
   FROM
      [User]
   WHERE
      id = @UserID
END
GO

CREATE PROC GetUserByOutputParams
  @UserID UniqueIdentifier,
  @Name NVARCHAR(255) OUTPUT,
  @EmailAddress NVARCHAR(500) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT 
      @Name =Name,
      @EmailAddress = EmailAddress
   FROM
      [User]
   WHERE
      id = @UserID
END
GO
```

Comment: I guess I should add as a comment, I've always prefered the recordset approach, but that just because it's the way I originally learnt.  One benefit to that approach that I can see is that it abstracts the underlying data type / size.  If Name increased in size within the table you'd need to modify the output parameter in all places referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two approaches is flexibility.  If you want to change the columns returned there is less work in changing a procedure which returns a recordset.

Answer (score 1):

I would return the single row and use a [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx) to access the information.  After all that single row may turn in to multiple rows.

Answer (score -2):

If you only return ID of a user, in order to get that user information your ORM would need to do another round-trip to the database to get additional information about that user.

I would just set up proper mapping between your entity and your sql tables and get all the necessary fields, instead of returning IDs.

But suppose we have a procedure, that returns hundreds of IDs, surely you don't want to return whole records of it if you do some intricate filtering of that data based on ids. So, ymmv.

Comment: I'm not really this answers the question that was asked and example given.  It is passing a unique ID and returning (limited) data associated with that record.  I was asking what was the better approach, a recordset, or output parameters, purely with respect to the example given.

Comment: @Paul Hadfield, two first sentences deal with your question. And the third is about what to keep in mind in other situations. Again, if you have an ORM that is synchronized with the database and has cached data of popular entities then you're okay with returning ID, otherwise you're better off returning all the necessary fields.